# Wrapping ManualResetEvent as awaitable task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'd like to await on a manual reset event with time-out and observing cancellation. I've come up with something like below. The manual reset event object is provided by an API beyond my control. Is there a way to make this happen without taking on and blocking a thread from ThreadPool?

```
static Task<bool> TaskFromWaitHandle(WaitHandle mre, int timeout, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        bool s = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { mre, ct.WaitHandle }, timeout) == 0;
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return s;
    }, ct);
}

// ...

if (await TaskFromWaitHandle(manualResetEvent, 1000, cts.Token))
{
    // true if event was set
}
else 
{
    // false if timed out, exception if cancelled 
}
```

**[EDITED]** Apparently, it [makes sense](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/05/13/registerwaitforsingleobject-and-mutexes-dont-mix/) to use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, the thing is in my case it has to be a real manual reset event, beyond my control. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: In that case I fully expect the answer to be "no" - wrapping a synchronous API in an asynchronous one typically *does* involve blocking a thread.

Comment: I was thinking about something like `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` or even unmanaged [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061(v=vs.85).aspx). I realize that technically there's still a kernel pool thread doing the wait, but in theory it could have some aggregation logic for single wait handles (e.g., using `WaitForMultipleObjects`), so one thread might serve several `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` requests. That'd be better than one-pool-thread-per-one-wait-handle like above.

Comment: @Noseratio So, what's stopping you from trying that?

Comment: It this is just a single event then, no, RWFSO doesn't optimize that.  It uses a dedicated wait thread, it can handle many RWFSO calls.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`RegisterWaitForSingleObject` will combine waits onto dedicated waiter threads, each of which can wait on multiple handles (specifically, 63 of them, which is `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` minus one for a "control" handle).

So you should be able to use something like this (warning: untested):

```
public static class WaitHandleExtensions
{
    public static Task AsTask(this WaitHandle handle)
    {
        return AsTask(handle, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }

    public static Task AsTask(this WaitHandle handle, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        var registration = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(handle, (state, timedOut) =>
        {
            var localTcs = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)state;
            if (timedOut)
                localTcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else
                localTcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }, tcs, timeout, executeOnlyOnce: true);
        tcs.Task.ContinueWith((_, state) => ((RegisteredWaitHandle)state).Unregister(null), registration, TaskScheduler.Default);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary. Is there a good reason to pass `tcs` as `state` here? Overall, would you consider this a preferred solution over using `WaitHandle.WaitAny`?

Comment: I'm using the state parameters on `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` and `ContinueWith` as an optimization. This is preferred over `WaitAny` because this wait can be combined with other waits.

Comment: @StephenCleary but why the type unsafety? `TaskCompletionSource<RegisteredWaitHandle>.Task` will still implicitly cast to `Task` just fine. Or if that wasn’t an option, you could get type safety by using automatic closure ;-).

Comment: @binki: Yes, you could use `TCS<RegisteredWaitHandle>` for a typesafe `ContinueWith` call. The `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` still wouldn't be typesafe, though. And yes, you can use closures but that prevents the allocation optimizations.

Comment: Hi, we've been using this technique as documented, but have discovered that Thread.CurrentPrincipal has been changed to a WindowsPrincipal after the await has finished..  I think this means are synchronization/security context has been lost?  Any idea how we can preserve it?

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy: That depends on your hosting environment. If you're on pre-Core ASP.NET, then double-check all your [settings and targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately we already have  targetFramework="4.6.1" for httpRuntime and compilation.

Comment: Ah - discovered the issue, we were setting/getting identity from Thread.CurrentPrincipal, but in a pure async controller (with no `ConfigureAwait(false)`) we really should be using HttpContext.Current.User as that is restored after awaiting

Comment: This should really be a part of the WaitHandle object in plain .Net, or if you like, something in System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the reason this isn't built-in is because it's inefficient compared to an async-native implementation. So, while this is a useful technique in some rare scenarios, it shouldn't be encouraged generally.

Comment: Well, here's the scenario I'm using it for: My web app has stuff it needs to initialize from the database. No need to make every Request thread wait on that, so it runs on a background Task after the app starts. Some pages depend on that data, which will be partly blank if a user hits them the moment the app is deployed, but otherwise fine. But if I debug those pages, and don't wait on that initial data, I get a blank page *every* *time*. So I'm using the above to await that before proceeding. Is there a better approach?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: Sounds like a one-time asynchronous signal. `ManualResetEvent` is a multi-use synchronous signal. It would *work*, sure, but I'd look into just using `Task<T>` instead of `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: The problem with that, is that the background Task it would be awaiting - if I just used the Task itself that is performing the work - has not necessarily been created or started, when the first Request thread comes asking. ManualResetEvent.AsTask (with a signal that just signals once to Go and never switches back) allows me to create the Task immediately and guarantee any Request thread that comes asking won't find a null Task and create a Race Condition.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: If you cannot guarantee that the `Task` variable would be set before requests arrive, you could use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I had memory leak problems with this implementation. I received a ManualResetEvent as parameter in a function, and used the AsTask on it, and found a lot of not disposed TaskCompletionSource<Object>, Task<Object>, StandardTaskContinuation, RegisteredWaitHandle, RegisteredWaithandleSafe, ContinuationResultTaskFromresultTask<Object,bool> and _ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback, using it, along a Task, as parameter of Task.WaitAny(). Couldn't understand what was not disposed. Any idea of why?

Comment: @JotaBe: I have a [more modern approach](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Interop.WaitHandles/Interop/WaitHandleAsyncFactory.cs) these days. Both approaches assume that the handle will eventually get signalled (or time out). If it is not, then the task will not be completed. So if you have a loop or something using it in a `*Any` method, your code could be starting a *new* wait each time instead of using the existing one.

Answer (score 13):

You also can use SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync() which is similar to ManualResetEvent

Comment: The problem is there is no "Wait without decrement". Sometimes you just want to wait and not decrement the counter.

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` is similar to `AutoResetEvent`, not `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: Another problem is that calling Reset() may through SemaphoreFullException if there is nothing to release left. Even when checking CurrentCount, just before calling Release(), I have situations, when multiple threads pass that check and try to release the semaphore. I am trying to avoid any possibility of exceptions, because they hurt performance.

Answer (score 5):

Stephen's Cleary solution looks perfect. Microsoft provides the [similar one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN#from-wait-handles-to-tap).

As I haven't seen an example with cancellation logic.

Here it is:

```
public static class WaitHandleExtensions
{
    public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken, int timeoutMilliseconds = Timeout.Infinite)
    {
        if (waitHandle == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(waitHandle));

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        CancellationTokenRegistration ctr = cancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
        TimeSpan timeout = timeoutMilliseconds > Timeout.Infinite ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds) : Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

        RegisteredWaitHandle rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle,
            (_, timedOut) =>
            {
                if (timedOut)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                }
            }, 
            null, timeout, true);

        Task<bool> task = tcs.Task;

        _ = task.ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            rwh.Unregister(null);
            return ctr.Unregister();
        }, CancellationToken.None);

        return task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give this one a shot, https://www.badflyer.com/asyncmanualresetevent , tried to build upon the example on https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx to support timeouts and cancellation.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// An async manual reset event.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ManualResetEventAsync
{
    // Inspiration from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/
    // and the .net implementation of SemaphoreSlim

    /// <summary>
    ///  The timeout in milliseconds to wait indefinitly.
    /// </summary>
    private const int WaitIndefinitly = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// True to run synchronous continuations on the thread which invoked Set. False to run them in the threadpool.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly bool runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current task completion source.
    /// </summary>
    private volatile TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ManualResetEventAsync"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isSet">True to set the task completion source on creation.</param>
    public ManualResetEventAsync(bool isSet)
        : this(isSet: isSet, runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread: true)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ManualResetEventAsync"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isSet">True to set the task completion source on creation.</param>
    /// <param name="runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread">If you have synchronous continuations, they will run on the thread which invokes Set, unless you set this to false.</param>
    public ManualResetEventAsync(bool isSet, bool runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread)
    {
        this.runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread = runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread;

        if (isSet)
        {
            this.completionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait for the manual reset event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A task which completes when the event is set.</returns>
    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        return this.AwaitCompletion(ManualResetEventAsync.WaitIndefinitly, default(CancellationToken));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait for the manual reset event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token">A cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>A task which waits for the manual reset event.</returns>
    public Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return this.AwaitCompletion(ManualResetEventAsync.WaitIndefinitly, token);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait for the manual reset event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">A timeout.</param>
    /// <param name="token">A cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>A task which waits for the manual reset event. Returns true if the timeout has not expired. Returns false if the timeout expired.</returns>
    public Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return this.AwaitCompletion((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, token);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait for the manual reset event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout">A timeout.</param>
    /// <returns>A task which waits for the manual reset event. Returns true if the timeout has not expired. Returns false if the timeout expired.</returns>
    public Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return this.AwaitCompletion((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, default(CancellationToken));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the completion source.
    /// </summary>
    public void Set()
    {
        if (this.runSynchronousContinuationsOnSetThread)
        {
            this.completionSource.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Run synchronous completions in the thread pool.
            Task.Run(() => this.completionSource.TrySetResult(true));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset the manual reset event.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        // Grab a reference to the current completion source.
        var currentCompletionSource = this.completionSource;

        // Check if there is nothing to be done, return.
        if (!currentCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, try to replace it with a new completion source (if it is the same as the reference we took before).
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.completionSource, new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(), currentCompletionSource);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Await completion based on a timeout and a cancellation token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeoutMS">The timeout in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="token">The cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>A task (true if wait succeeded). (False on timeout).</returns>
    private async Task<bool> AwaitCompletion(int timeoutMS, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Validate arguments.
        if (timeoutMS < -1 || timeoutMS > int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The timeout must be either -1ms (indefinitely) or a positive ms value <= int.MaxValue");
        }

        CancellationTokenSource timeoutToken = null;

        // If the token cannot be cancelled, then we dont need to create any sort of linked token source.
        if (false == token.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            // If the wait is indefinite, then we don't need to create a second task at all to wait on, just wait for set. 
            if (timeoutMS == -1)
            {
                return await this.completionSource.Task;
            }

            timeoutToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
        else
        {
            // A token source which will get canceled either when we cancel it, or when the linked token source is canceled.
            timeoutToken = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
        }

        using (timeoutToken)
        {
            // Create a task to account for our timeout. The continuation just eats the task cancelled exception, but makes sure to observe it.
            Task delayTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMS, timeoutToken.Token).ContinueWith((result) => { var e = result.Exception; }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

            var resultingTask = await Task.WhenAny(this.completionSource.Task, delayTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // The actual task finished, not the timeout, so we can cancel our cancellation token and return true.
            if (resultingTask != delayTask)
            {
                // Cancel the timeout token to cancel the delay if it is still going.
                timeoutToken.Cancel();
                return true;
            }

            // Otherwise, the delay task finished. So throw if it finished because it was canceled.
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution: wait for the handles of the task and the manual reset event**

I was having memory leaks when using `Task.WaitAny()` with a `Task` (returned by SqlConnection.OpenAsync()') and a Manual Reset Event received as parameter and wrapped in a `Task` with `AsTask()`. These object were not being disposed: `TaskCompletionSource<Object>, Task<Object>, StandardTaskContinuation, RegisteredWaitHandle, RegisteredWaithandleSafe, ContinuationResultTaskFromresultTask<Object,bool>, _ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback`).

This is real production code, used in a Windows service, of a function that tries to open a connection to a db in a loop until the connection is opened, or the operation fails, or the `ManualResetEvent _finishRequest`, received as parameter in the function containing this code, is signaled by code in any other thread.

To avoid the leak, I decided to do it the other way round: wait for the handles of the `_finishRequest` and the `Task` returned by `OpenAsync()`:

```cs
Task asyncOpening = sqlConnection.OpenAsync();

// Wait for the async open to finish, or until _finishRequest is signaled
var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[]
{
  // index 0 in array: extract the AsyncWaitHandle from the Task
  ((IAsyncResult)asyncOpening).AsyncWaitHandle,
  // index 1:
  _finishRequest
};

// Check if finish was requested (index of signaled handle in the array = 1)
int whichFinished = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
finishRequested = whichFinished == 1;
// If so, break the loop to exit immediately
if (finishRequested)
  break;
                    
// If not, check if OpenAsync finished with error (it's a Task)
if (asyncOpening.IsFaulted)
{
  // Extract the exception from the task, and throw it
  // NOTE: adapt it to your case. In mine, I'm interested in the inner exception,
  // but you can check the exception itself, for example to see if it was a timeout,
  // if you specified it in the call to the async function that returns the Task
  var ex = asyncOpening?.Exception?.InnerExceptions?[0];
  if (ex != null) throw ex; 
}
else
{
  Log.Verbose("Connection to database {Database} on server {Server}", database, server);
  break;
}
```

If you also need the timeout, you can include it in the call to `OpenAsync`, or you asyn function, and then check if the result of the async operation was cancelled because of the timeout: check the status of the Task when finished, as you can see in the NOTE in the code comment.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` package, then you will be able to use the `AsyncManualResetEvent` class, which by its own documentation states:

> A flavor of ManualResetEvent that can be asynchronously awaited on.

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncmanualresetevent