# C# Best practice for synchronizing a collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Given the following, what would be the best synchronization technician

*** Please note that this an example model and there are much more things going on.**

The shared resource is the instruments dictionary which is updated from 2 places:

(1) an inner value is being rapidly updated.

(2) the entire collection is refreshed.

```
  public class Insturment
  {
       public Feed Feed{ get; set;}
  }

  static IDictionary<string,Instrument> instruments = new Dictionary<string,Instrument>();

   // (1) This happens frequently  
   public void OnNewFeed(Feed feed)
   {
       instruments[feed.Symbol].Feed = feed;
   }

   // (2) happens every few hours ,or manually triggered at any given time 
   public void BuildInstruments()
   {
        foreach(var instrument in newInstruments)
        {
             instruments.AddOrUpdate(insturment.Symbol,insturment);
        }     
   }
```

I thought of the same basic concept block threads on UpdateFeed() when the entire collection is being rebuilt using a manual reset event.

```
   ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

   public void OnNewFeed(Feed feed)
   {
       _mre.WaitOne();
       instruments[feed.Symbol].Feed = feed;
   }

   public void BuildInstruments()
   {
        _mre.Reset();

        foreach(var instrument in newInstruments)
        {
             instruments.AddOrUpdate(insturment.Symbol,insturment);
        }

        _mre.Set();     
   }
```

Or the same thing using any kind of Task wrapper and awaiting it. 
something like this construct : [The anser by Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756354/wrapping-manualresetevent-as-awaitable-task)

- Side note I don't care about data integraty when reading from the dictionary. meaning i don't mind some one receiving non-updated values from the dictionary at any given point. I do mind the actual update from being lost for ever because i just replaced the entire instrument that was being updated.

Questions :

1) Can any one think of a better approach to synchronize the operations on instruments dictionary.

2) Is there any advantages of using async/await on a task wrapping the WaitHandle ? ( like the one described in the link above)

Comment: Use a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: lets say that i am please describe how that would aid me.
and i'm glad you brought it up. :)
please notice 2 things i'm replacing the entire instrument object in Build() and i don't want to loose the new Feed coming in while i replacing that parent object in the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, forget it :), unless you expect to have multiple OnNewFeed from different sources then it will not help you, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> Best practice for synchronizing a collection

I would say the best practice is to use `lock` unless you *need* something else.

E.g., if you need asynchronous locking, you can use `SemaphoreSlim` or one of the `AsyncLock` implementations.

> Or the same thing using any kind of Task wrapper and awaiting it.

I would not use that solution for collection synchronization. If you need async-compatible synchronization, then use an async-compatible synchronization primitive (such as `SemaphoreSlim` or `AsyncLock`). And if you don't need it, then just use `lock`.

The `Task`-wrapper-around-`WaitHandle` situation is really only needed if you *have* to use a `WaitHandle`-based object (e.g., it's shared between *processes*) and want to consume it with asynchronous code. It doesn't sound like that scenario applies here.

> Side note I don't care about data integraty when reading from the dictionary. meaning i don't mind some one receiving non-updated values from the dictionary at any given point.

I do recommend locking on reads anyway. There's a variety of problems (like tearing) that can occur if you don't.

Just as a side note: your description of your scenario keeps using the term "update". It sounds like you may want more of a producer/consumer solution, or possibly a publish/subscribe like Rx, rather than a shared, synchronized collection.