# Await keyboard event in a Console application

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there a way to get a `Task` that completes and returns a key press without a dedicated thread?

```
// Kernel callback, not a new thread in my process waiting for a keyboard event
var key = await KeyPress();
```

As `Console.ReadKey()` is a blocking call and uses a thread only to wait for user input.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620603/non-blocking-read-from-standard-i-o-in-c-sharp/5620647#5620647

Comment: @mxmissile one thread is still busy looping and running ReadKey

Comment: Are you not OK with having a dedicated (yet single) thread that'd be blocking waiting for console input? Then you can use something like consumer/producer pattern to asynchronously consume the console input on other threads.

Comment: @Noseratio that is the thing, a thread dedicated only to wait for user input sounds like a waste (not necessarily a big one, but it feels like it should have an implementation for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that is the thing, a thread dedicated only to wait for user input sounds like a waste
>   (not necessarily a big one, but it feels like it should have an
>   implementation for this).

I wouldn't be concerned about this for a console app that expects user input.

Anyhow, it *might* be possible to achieve what you're after by using some underlying Win32 APIs. The docs for [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx) say:

> **A process can specify a console input buffer handle in one of the wait
>   functions to determine when there is unread console input.** When the
>   input buffer is not empty, the state of a console input buffer handle
>   is signaled. To determine the number of unread input records in a
>   console's input buffer, use the `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`
>   function. To read input records from a console input buffer without
>   affecting the number of unread records, use the `PeekConsoleInput`
>   function. To discard all unread records in a console's input buffer,
>   use the `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` function.

So, in theory, you could use a handle returned by [`GetStdHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass it to 
[`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061(v=vs.85).aspx). Then you could convert it to an awaitable task using `TaskCompletionSource`, e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766131/1768303).

I haven't verified this in practice. It shoudn't be blocking a thread, but IMO, again, the game isn't worth the candle.

Comment: [Console.ReadKey](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,1476) uses ReadConsoleInput itself *with* a lock to prevent multiple threads from calling it concurrently. A correct implementation would have to replicate that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, not sure I understood your point. The OP doesn't need to `Console.ReadKey` (or `ReadConsoleInput`) to await for the input asynchronously. He just need the std input handle and to register a callack with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. Then - once he's got notified of the available input - he can use `ReadKey` to read it on whatever thread he currently is. As long as he doesn't call `ReadKey` from multple threads semultaneosly, I suppose.

Comment: @Noseratio that is likely to be the solution, I will try and implement it and give some feedback. I was exactly looking at some kernel callback to wrap in a TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try it; works, but the documentation of `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` states: "Directs a wait thread in the thread pool to wait on the object. The wait thread queues the specified callback function to the thread pool when one of the following occurs" so it will block a thread anyway I presume. Just in a more fancy and complex way. EDIT: Maybe I'm wrong, a wait thread is something different...

Comment: The experiment works, but the handle gets signaled for so many events beside the keyboard input that it is actually firing up even MORE threads degrading performances. I will mark your answer as correct as it was quite useful and in theory does the trick.

Comment: @user4388177, thanks for an update. `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` does block a thread but it does it cummulatively for up to as many as 63 handles.

Comment: @Noseratio interesting, thank you. Indeed it looks like a so called "wait thread" is just a regular thread ( mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ) but definitely good it handles multiple handles.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the standard input stream, which has asynchronous operations for reading:

```
using (var stream = Console.OpenStandardInput())
{
    var buffer = new byte[1];
    var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
    char c = (char)buffer[0];
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: `ReadAsync` does not return unless you hit enter.

Comment: @user4388177 That's an inherent problem you're going to have with the console; it buffers input.