# How to use TaskCompletionSource

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

I am having a situation of multi-producer and single consumer.I have opted for a common `thread-safe` resource that in which all producers `Enqueue` items.
However i do not know how to efficiently make the producer `await` for new items when `Dequeue`-ing from that resource.

**POCO**

```
struct Sample
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public  double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

**Producers**

```
class ProducerGroup
    {
        StorageQueue sink;
        int producerGroupSize;

        public ProducerGroup(StorageQueue _sink,int producers)
        {
            this.sink = _sink;
            this.producerGroupSize = producers;
        }
        public void StartProducers()
        {
            Task[] producers = new Task[producerGroupSize];
            int currentProducer;
            for (int i = 0; i < producerGroupSize; i++)
            {
                currentProducer = i;
                producers[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
                  {
                      int cycle = 0;
                      while (true)
                      {
                          if (cycle > 5)
                          {
                              cycle = 0;
                          }
                          Sample localSample = new Sample { Id = currentProducer, Value = cycle++ };
                          await Task.Delay(1000);
                          this.sink.Enqueue(localSample);
                      }
                  });
            }

        }
    }
```

**Storage**

```
class StorageQueue
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<Sample> tcs;
        private object @lock = new object();

        private Queue<Sample> queue;

        public static StorageQueue CreateQueue(int?size=null)
        {
            return new StorageQueue(size);
        }

        public StorageQueue(int ?size)
        {
            if (size.HasValue)
            {
                this.queue = new Queue<Sample>(size.Value);
            }
            else
                this.queue = new Queue<Sample>();
        }

        public void Enqueue(Sample value)
        {
            lock (this.@lock)
            {
                this.queue.Enqueue(value);
                tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Sample>();
                tcs.SetResult(this.queue.Peek());
            }
        }
        public async Task<Sample> DequeueAsync()
        {
            var result=await this.tcs.Task;
            this.queue.Dequeue();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Consumer**

```
class Consumer
    {
        private StorageQueue source;
        public Consumer(StorageQueue _source)
        {
            this.source = _source;
        }
        public async Task ConsumeAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Sample arrivedSample = await this.source.DequeueAsync();  //how should i implement this ?
                Console.WriteLine("Just Arrived");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the `Consumer`class i would like to  wrap my `Storage's method`Dequeue`in a`Task`so that i can`await`it in my`Consumer`.
The only reason i used`TaskCompletionSource`is to be able to communicate between the`Dequeue`and`Enqueue`methods in the`Storage`.

I do not know if i need to reinitialize the `tcs` but i suppose i do since i want a new `Task` after every `Enqueue` operation.

I also reinitialized the `tcs` inside the `lock` since i want that particular instance to set the result.

How should i proceed with this? Is the implementation ok ? Would `System.Reactive` offer a better option ?

Comment: There's many options out there for the producer/consumer pattern, try [Blocking Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview), [TPL-Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern), [RX](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/4/19/processing-pipelines-series-reactive-extensions-rxnet) or [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see several issues with your implementation:

1. If you call `Enqueue()` multiple times without calling `DequeueAsync()`, you will lose the `TaskCompletionSource` and have only the last one.  Then, calling `DequeueAsync()` will not yield correct results after the first call.

To fix this, you will need a queue of `TaskCompletionSource`'s for this.  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766131/383426) and further [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/).

Better, use [SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) in `DequeueAsync` to wait properly if the queue is empty.

2. You also don't protect your queue in `DequeueAsync()`.