# Deadlock using manualResetEvent - c#

Tags: c#, deadlock, manualresetevent

In My Sample UI, there are 3 buttons. Start button, pause, resume. The start button is async/await and will call a method:

```
private async void btnStart_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(() => StartingMethod());
}
```

and we have a global `ManualResetEvent` named `_pauseEvent`.
and here is the structure of `StartingMethod()`:

```
public void StartingMethod()
{
   for (int i =0; i < 1000000; i++)
   {
      _pauseEvent.WaitOne();
      // Do Something
   }
}
```

and here is pause/resume buttons:

```
private async void btnPause_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(() => _pauseEvent.Reset());
}

private async void btnResume_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(() => _pauseEvent.Set());
}
```

but sometimes it will give `The handle is invalid` for the `ManualResetEvent` on pause/resume call. It seems it is a race condition problem. so I decided to create a global lock object.

```
Object _lockObject = new object();
```

and here is the new ones:

```
public void StartingMethod()
{
   for (int i =0; i < 1000000; i++)
   {
      lock (_lockObject)
         _pauseEvent.WaitOne();
      // Do Something
   }
}

private async void btnPause_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(() => lock (_lockObject) _pauseEvent.Reset());
}

private async void btnResume_Click()
{
    await Task.Run(() => lock (_lockObject) _pauseEvent.Set());
}
```

But it seems, here again, I will face a DeadLock problem with the lock object.
How can I handle such a situation?

Comment: why do you need to wrap `_pauseEvent.Reset()` and `_pauseEvent.Set()` in a `Task.Run` ?

Comment: It's just a simple view of my work. pausing may take some minutes to do, so I can not freeze the UI. so I should use `Task.Run`

Comment: Could you please post full  `StartingMethod` ?

Comment: you think in the Rest of `StatringMethod` I'm converting some videos...

Comment: If you get an invalid handle error for `_pauseEvent` it must be an issue with the lifetime of the handle. Do you create/destroy new event instances as you go?

Comment: BTW, deadlock is not the same as invalid handle. If you actually get a deadlock it would be helpful to know the calls stacks when this occurs.

Comment: You probably need a fully async version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756354/wrapping-manualresetevent-as-awaitable-task

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I just only create a new instance of `ManualResetEvent` once

Comment: That was the wrong way to deal with this issue, now you have two problems.  It is *not* a race problem, "The handle is invalid" indicates a much more serious issue.  One that the snippet gives no hints to.  Start by observing the number of handles your program creates with Task Manager, add the "Handles" column.  A steadily increasing count is not going to end well.   If it doesn't then you'll have to suspect memory corruption issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure using `async void`, `Task.Run` and `lock` would result in a deadlock. What I suggest to do is use a `CancellationToken` together with some intermediate state to represent a progress of `StartingMethod`.

Pay attetion it will not handle concurrent execution of many `StartingMethod`s and you would need to use something like `CanExecute` to prevent user from clicking start button many times in a row.

```cs
private int _state = 0;

public void StartingMethod(CancellationToken cancellation, bool resetState)
{
   if (resetState)
   {
       _state = 0;
      // reset your additional data  
   }
   for (int i = _state; i < 1000000; i++)
   {
      if (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
      { 
          // Recover saved state
          // Do Something
      }
      else
      {
          // save intermediate state
          // save your additional data
          _state = i;
      }
   }
}
```

I would strongly suggest to add try-catch to an `async` method:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async Task HandleStart(bool resetState)
{ 
   _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => StartingMethod(_cts.Token, resetState));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    // log or show some error on UI
    }
    finally
    {
        _cts.Dispose();
    }
}

private void btnStart_Click()
{
    // No need to await because it's a single statement in a method
    HandleStart(true);
}

private async void btnPause_Click()
{
    _cts.Cancel();
}

private void btnResume_Click()
{
    HandleStart(false);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but you are trying to give me a solution for handling the loop inside the `Starting Method`. my question is about to handle the `ManualResetEvent` in a thread-safe manner